# Appcache caches pages that are not included in manifest

Tags: html, codeigniter, html5-appcache

I have a codeigniter site and i want to store the following files via appcache: jquery.js, style.css and offline.html (fallback).

So, naturally, manifest file looks like the one below. my manifest file is called, well, manifest.appcache.

```
CACHE MANIFEST:

jquery.js
style.css

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/ /offline.html
```

i open my site and i do see that the .js, .css and .html files are downloaded. but then i see that the page http://mysite.com/home (default route in codeigniter) is also download. what gives? i did not include this in my manifest file.

Comment: figured it out. i cleared all my browser cache and i cached the login page instead. i read the documentation and it fails to say that wherever you include your appcache becomes that master file and it will ALWAYS be cached.

Answer (score 0):

This is from w3 standard documentation: Any page with a manifest attribute in the HTML element will be cached, even if not included in the manifest file even if included in NETWORK: